# Visa in old passport with stamp on visa

Tags: visas

My visa is in an expired passport but is valid until 2022.
My only problem is that there is a stamp on the top of the visa from NYC.  Will I have problem at the airport?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No you will not.  It's common to place the admission stamp across the edge of the visa the first time it is used.

I assume that this is a US visa and that you're asking about using it to travel to the US, and that you also have a newer valid passport.  If not, please edit your question to clarify, though I don't think it would change the answer.

Comment: Hello, thank you for your answer. Yes you are right, I have a US visa and I will travel next month to LA.

Comment: Wait, she said she have an expired passeport, how is this not a problem ?

Comment: @Antzi, presumably she has a valid passport, in addition to the expired passport containing the valid visa.

Comment: @CarlotaJoaquina I've edited my answer. Do you also have a new valid passport?